# Provider 'browserFingerprint' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with angular factory, but i don't know what happened with it

This example of my code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ofsApp')
  .factory('browserFingerprint', ['$document', 
    function($document){
        var CryptoJS;``
        function getFingerprint(username, password) {

        var isIE = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1);
        var navParam = + username + ';' + password + ';' + navigator.userAgent + ';' + navigator.appCodeName + ';' + navigator.appName + ';' + 
        navigator.appVersion + ';' + navigator.mimeTypes + ';' + navigator.platform + ';' + 
        navigator.product + ';' + navigator.userAgent;
        if (isIE) {
            navParam += ';' + username + ';' + password + ';' + navigator.userLanguage + ';' + navigator.systemLanguage;
        }
        else {
        navParam += ';' + navigator.languageanguage;
        }
        var script = $document[0].createElement('script');
        script.src = 'vendors/CryptoMD5.js';
        ($document[0].head || $document[0].documentElement).appendChild(script);
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
        var cryptoObject = CryptoJS.MD5(navParam);
        return cryptoObject.toString();
    }
}


 ]);
```

there shows an error : Provider 'browserFingerprint' must return a value from $get factory method.

What should i do ?

Comment: did you try logging `cryptoObject.toString()`  to the console ? is it undefined or does it return a value ?

Comment: my problem is solved. thanks :)